# Applying javascript to mustache created objects

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a mustache template in my javascript which gets put into my html

This is made up of H2 tags and ul/li tags

I have this at the bottom of my javascript

```
    function vara(){
        alert('f')
    }

    $('h2').click(vara)
```

However this does not work when I click on H2 tags created by the mustache template. How can I remedy this?

Comment: Probably `$(document).on("click", "h2", vara);`

Comment: This actually works. Why does this work but not  my method?

Comment: Posted an answer craig - hopefully this clears some things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content is being added by mustache after run-time, and since your handlers are bound at run-time, they have no idea what to bind to. The correct way is to use `.on` and bind the click event to the container of your appended content.

```
$(document).on("click", "h2", vara);
```

Comment: What about if I didn't want a click event but just wanted a function to run AFTER the mustache has been implimented?

Comment: @craig-- Not sure, probably ask another question on that

Answer (score 2):

By waiting for a document to be [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).